# What is the correct noun for "apartment viewing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please read the following:

> The broker will show the apartment/house/land on Saturday.

What is the correct noun for the action of showing a property to potential buyers? Is the broker doing an "exhibition", "viewing" or "show"?

Comment: Any of the above.

Comment: Isn't "exhibition" more related to works of art?

Comment: It depends a lot on the value and location of the property, up-market brokers/agents will be more likely to use arty terms like "exhibition" to make it seem more special.

Comment: In the UK, for residential properties, "viewing" would be the best choice.

Comment: "Showing" is probably most idiomatic in the US.

Comment: UK estate agent: can we meet at two o'clock? Other estate agent: sorry, I've got a viewing at that time. Will four suit you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the phrase used by realtors most often, at least in the United States, is, "The broker has a showing." We've been through several property sales and have one in progress right now. Our realtor often says to us, "We have a showing today."

I've noticed, though, that there's a problem with finding additional verbs to accompany the word "showing" when it's used as a noun. "Hold a showing" or "Do a showing" both sound strange. "I'm attending a showing," however, sounds fine.

Comment: Agree re *showing* in the U.S. *Hosting* or *having* or *arranging* a showing would work from the realtor side. And *going* to a showing would also work from the prospective-buyer side.

Comment: Good points about hosting and arranging. And of course going.

Comment: There are two kinds of events: a showing by appointment and an open house, usually on the weekend.  In the States in upscale neighborhoods one  goes to look at houses or makes an appointment to see them.